# Is this sentence correct - ' I have all the more reason to not be missing your show'?

Tags: grammar

I am confused if this sounds correct -

> I have all the more reason to not be missing out on your show

Or is this correct -

> I have all the more reason to not be missing on your show

I intend to convey that now I have more reasons to not miss watching your show.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close. The most natural way of saying this would be

> All the more reason not to miss your show.

Your first example isn't technically incorrect from a grammatical standpoint, just a bit unnatural. The second example isn't grammatically correct, though it is still understandable.

Your understanding and use of "all the more" seems accurate, especially as you explained it in your comment to @Michael Harvey (Edit: I see that answer was deleted, but you indicated (correctly) that "all the more reason" means you already had a reason, but now you have more). Now, "all the more reason" *is* something of a set phrase, so adding "I have" feels unnecessary, but it's not wrong. What *is* wrong (or at least unnatural) is your tense in the latter half.

"To be missing your show" is not technically wrong, but it *is* unnatural and slightly clumsy. The most natural way of thinking about this in English is not that you're worried about being in the middle of the showtime and not being there, it's that you don't want to miss it at all. **The show is not being thought of as a period of time, but rather as a cohesive whole: you either see it or you miss it.**

Comment: Is there a particular dialect or situation in which you think "missing *on* your show" is used?  It sounds very unnatural to me.

Comment: Thanks for explaining so well @Aos Sidhe

Comment: @stangdon I gave it some more thought, and I think you're right. Even when I wouldn't think it entirely unacceptable, it would be very noticeable. I think it would be a derivation of "missing out on X" -> "missing on X" as a sort of intentionally ungrammatical construction for effect (maybe to indicate casualness, effect a character, etc), or to emulate constructions like "hating on X", "clowning on X", etc, so it would definitely be a very slangy, colloquial usage, and I wouldn't recommend it to even native speakers. I'll edit the post to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

**all the more reason** is an idiomatic expression in English used in response to a comment by another person, usually.

It is used in the context of an argument about something.

John: Well, David left his room in a mess with dirty clothes everywhere.

Mary: **That's all the more reason he shouldn't go out** with his friends today.

John: This is David's last show for the winter season.
Mary: (That's) all the more reason for not missing it.